# Visual Basic problem with Trimming values corectly

Tags: vb.net

I’m making a program to crawl a webpage source and to display it in a datagridview but it fails to display the result correctly because of some inconsistency and it does not end displaying it on the correct place either.

What I have:

```vb
Private Function ExtractSide(sourceCode As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String = "Side: (.*?) [\/li]"
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(sourceCode, pattern)

    If match.Success Then
        Return match.Groups(1).Value
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

The text strings in the source are one of the following

```
Side: Both[/li]
Side: None[/li]
Side: [span class=icon-alliance]Alliance[/span][/li]
Side: [span class=icon-horde]Horde[/span][/li]
```

I only want to be left with Both, None, Alliance or Horde.

Comment: If it comes from a web page, did it start out as HTML? If yes, then you can use an HTML parser (there are a few compared at [C# HTML parsers](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/csharp-html-parser/)) to get the text.

Comment: Regex is powerful but does not a good job in parsing HTML because of its nested structures. Use the [Html Agility Pack (HAP)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) instead.

Comment: I tryed to use HtmlAgilityPack earlyer   ```  Private Function ExtractSide(sourceCode As String) As String
        Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode)
        Dim sideNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//text()[contains(., 'Side:')]/..")
        If sideNode IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sideText As String = sideNode.InnerText.Trim()
            sideText = Regex.Replace(sideText, "<[^>]+>", "")
            Return sideText
        End If
        Return String.Empty
    End Function ``` but this loads everything inside a  <script>

Comment: need to find a way to trim it down then

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in the debugger?  What's going wrong, specifically? "Some inconsistency" and "not on the correct place" are too vague to be useful.

Comment: As written, it looks like you'll get back one of "Both", "None", "[span class=icon-alliance]Alliance[/span]", or "[span class=icon-horde]Horde[/span]".  You might need a second processing pass to strip out the "span" bracketing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Dim pattern = "Side: (\[[^]]*])?(.*?)(\[[^]]*])"`, then return group 2 instead of group 1:

```
Public Shared Function ExtractSide(sourceCode As String) As String
    Dim pattern = "Side: (\[[^]]*])?(.*?)(\[[^]]*])"
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(sourceCode, pattern)

    If match.Success Then
        Return match.Groups(2).Value
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I see  so the Groups(X) is releated to what pattern to match so 2 is the second. care to explain abit moore about the logic why im after 2 to match what im after?

Comment: Group 0 is the whole matching text. Group 1 is the first part of the pattern in parentheses, namely "(\[[^]]*])", which matches anything in square braces. Group 2 is the second part of the pattern in parentheses, namely "(.*)", and so on.